# download a file from asp.net api in xamarin form?

Tags: asp.net, api, xamarin.forms

I have a asp.net boiler plate project and a xamarin form app for that.

I need to download the files that has stored on api.

the files saves as byte[] and I don't have url. how can I download them in app?

at the moment I have this but I don't have any url!

```
 private async void DownloadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var fileId = (int)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
            var document = await _projectAppService.GetProjectFileById(fileId);
            var downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;

            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
           var file = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(//// what should I put here??);
                downloadManager.Start(file);


            });


            var id = (int)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
            var file2 = await _projectAppService.GetProjectFileById(id);

        }
    }
```

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about downloading a file from a REST service in C#

Comment: all of them downloading file via url